# Override model association conditional for particular functionality

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a User model that will return user studies that have a status of true:

```
has_many :user_studies, -> { where(status: true) }, dependent: :destroy
```

I am using this for over 80% of my functionality but there are some instances where I want to override this line of code.

I have a private method in the User controller that does the work of getting a user study:

```
def set_user_study
  @user_study = @user.user_studies.find(params[:id])
end
```

@user is set in another private method:

```
def set_user
  @user = users_api.find_by_guid(params[:user_id])
rescue Longboat::Api::Users::NotFound => e
  logger.error e.message
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

The private method is called when I try to edit a user_study(among others):

```
before_action :set_user_study, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

I am getting the following error(obviously) when trying to edit a study that does not have a status of true:

```
Couldn't find UserStudy with 'id'=1 [WHERE "user_studies"."user_id" = ? AND "user_studies"."status" = 't']
```

How can I continue to call the private method but allow a user to be able to edit  a user study whether the status is true or not?

Comment: `before_action  :set_user_study,...` inside a controller right...?

Comment: show the `edit` action inside the controller..

Comment: Ok.. Then from where you are setting this `@user` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to just override the association, don't use `@user.user_studies` . Instead, query out the values and use `UserStudy.where(user_id: @user.id)` in the private method. However, if the usage of `user_studies` is less in existing code, then just remove the condition in association and chain scopes to add this condition.

Comment: Do you have a link to querying out the values documentation?

Comment: No i mean just do UserStudy.where(user_id: @user.id) in the private method. This would give you all the user_studies.

Comment: I think that is working good so far, Thanks, I will get back to you.

Comment: you mean the conditional one you had or the one i suggested above ?

Comment: The one you suggested above 'UserStudy.where(user_id: @user.id)', but I am still playing around with it.

Comment: The answer you gave in the comments is good but I don't know if it is the best solution or not. If you edit your answer to reflect the comment you made, I will give you points but I won't be accepting any answers just yet, I want to keep it open for another while.

Comment: @adrianmann Yes. This will just get the job done. Will try to think more about this. Edited the answer anyways.